# PHP RegEx replace

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm trying to write a PHP Script that replaces auto-generated Content from a WordPress Plugin. The Plugin isn't able to provide a WYSIWYG Editor for special fields but it can recognize new lines. My Output would look like this:

```
Some Text that has to
go over a few
lines of code
because it's actually supposed to be a list
```

when the client writes inside these field all lines get `<br>` tags at the end, so I tried to find and replace them with `</li>` tags as well as adding a `<li>` in front of every new line. My PHP Script looks like this:

```
 $text = types_render_field("field-name");

 $pattern = array();
 $pattern[0] = "/br/"; // br tags
 $pattern[1] = "/\n/"; // new lines
 $replacements = array();
 $replacements[0] = "/li"; // replacement for <br>
 $replacements[1] = "<li>"; // insert into every new line (\n)

 echo "<ul>"; // wrapping the <li>'s
 echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacements, $text);
 echo "</ul>";
```

It's actually working so far but the first line get's no `<li>` in front of it so my question is: How do I get a `<li>` in front of the first line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple. Instead of

```
echo "<ul>"; // wrapping the <li>'s
```

Use:

```
echo "<ul><li>"; // wrapping the <li>'s
```

OR else:

Instead of:

```
$pattern[1] = "/\n/"; // new lines
```

Use:

```
$pattern[1] = "/^|\n/"; // new lines OR start
```

Comment: Damn... :( It's always the same, I'm thinking way too complex. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$pattern = "/(.+?)(<br>|$)/i"; // capture the text before the br tag
$replacement = "<li>$1</li>"; 
echo "<ul>"; 
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the text at the end of the string will almost certainly not be followed by a `<br>` tag.

Comment: You're right! I didn't thought about it. But with anubhava solution I can add "echo "</li></ul>" so the last one gets closed, too. Thanks for pointing me on that.